# Specific xPath and Regex - Web Crawling

Tags: regex, iframe, xpath, web-scraping

I'm currently in the process of trying to scrape a website. The problem is the information is placed on google maps in an iframe. Specifically, Latitude and Longitude.

I'm able to get all the other information I currently need expect this. Searching around, and working with import.io tech support, I found I need to use specific xPath and Regex to pull this information but the code I found on the site has me lost. Ideally I'd like to pull Latitude and Longitude separately. This is the code I have to work with.

What are my options? Thank you.

```
<div class="padding-listItem--sm">
  <iframe width="100%" height="310" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=33.3929503,-111.908652&amp;key=AIzaSyDK08tC4NRubbIiw-xwDR1WEp-YAXX1Mx8" style="border:0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: If the solution proposed works for you please accept it or explain why it doesn't, i'll try to update the answer as well

Answer (score 0):

1) Get the `src` attribute of the `iframe` element.

```
string srcText = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")).getAttribute("src");
```

2) Parse the url (found in `srcText`) for the latitude and longitude values.

Regex to find both numbers:

```
/([-]?\d+\.\d+)/g
```

when the url is as you specified:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=33.3929503,-111.908652&amp;key=AIzaSyDK08tC4NRubbIiw-xwDR1WEp-YAXX1Mx8"
```

Answer (score 0):

The **XPath** to obtain the `iframe` source is:

```
//div[@class='padding-listItem--sm']/iframe/@src
```

Then you can apply a regex like this one to obtain **latitude** and **longitude**

```
 /q=(-?[\d\.]*),(-?[\d\.]*)/g
```

Implementation online [Here](https://regex101.com/r/gI1lR7/1)